# Prove $\sqrt{n+1} < \sqrt{n} + 1 $

Tags: inequality, induction, radicals, formal-proofs

Prove $\sqrt{n+1} < \sqrt{n} + 1 $ for all $n \ge 1$. 
I have proven the base step for $n = 1$. $\sqrt{2}$ is less than $2$. The inductive hypothesis is $\sqrt{n+1} < \sqrt{n} + 1$. From here, I am unsure of how to proceed. How can I show that the inequality $\sqrt{(k+1)+ 1} < \sqrt{k+1} + 1$? After simplifying the expression $\sqrt{(k+1)+1}$, it becomes $\sqrt{k+2}$. Perhaps I can use this somehow to come up with an expression? The right hand side does not have a radical over the 1, so I do not think it is a duplicate question that has an answer in the suggested question.

Comment: You don't need induction. See for example [Does $\sqrt{a+b} \le \sqrt a + \sqrt b$ hold for all positive real numbers a and b?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1650642/does-sqrtab-le-sqrt-a-sqrt-b-hold-for-all-positive-real-numbers-a-and).

Comment: This is not really a case for induction $-$ you can get the result immediately just by squaring both sides.

Comment: Square both sides and you get$$n+1<n+1+\sqrt{2n}$$

Comment: $n$ doesn't have to be natural or $\ge 1$.  $n$ could be any real > 0. And if n = 0 the values are equal.

Comment: @Simply you mean $n + 1 + 2\sqrt{n}.$

Comment: @fleablood Oh, whoops.  Not that it makes too much of a difference...

Comment: No, it doesn't.  I made a similar error in my answer.

Comment: For a simple proof without induction, rewrite the desired inequality as $\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} < 1$. Now multiply both sides by $\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}$ to see why it holds.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

To prove by induction:
Consider n=1, $\sqrt {1+1} \lt \sqrt{1} + 1$
$$\sqrt{2} \lt 2$$
Assume n=k true:
$$\sqrt{k+1}\lt \sqrt{k} + 1$$
Consider n=k+1:
If true, this would mean that:
$$\sqrt{k+2}\lt\sqrt{k+1} + 1$$
We know that $\sqrt{k+1}\lt \sqrt{k} + 1$, so:
$$\sqrt{k+1} + 1 \lt \sqrt{k} + 2$$
Hence:
$$\sqrt{k+2}\lt\sqrt{k+1} + 1\lt\sqrt{k} + 2$$
Squaring both sides:
$$k+2\lt k + 4 + 4\sqrt{k}$$
This is indeed true, so n=1 true, and n=k true implies that n=k+1 true hence true for all natural numbers (integers greater than or equal to 1).

Comment: I see I have been downvoted, but I don't understand what the problem is with this answer, as it has actually done what was asked, and proved it by induction. Is there an error in my working??

Comment: You have shown that if the statement holds for $n = k+1$ ("if true, this would mean that..."), then it holds for $n=k+1$.

Answer (score 1):

**A geometric proof:**

Consider two segments of lengths $1$ and $\sqrt{n}$. If you attach these segments by their endpoints at an angle of $90^\circ$ (so they become two legs of a right triangle), then by Pythagorean theorem the hypotenuse of this right triangle is $\sqrt{n+1}$.

Now increase the angle between the two "leg" segments. By the law of cosines, the distance between the "loose" endpoints also increases, until the angle becomes $180^\circ$. But now at $180^\circ$, the distance between the "loose" endpoints is just the sum of the two segments $\sqrt{n}+1$; therefore
$$\sqrt{n+1} < \sqrt{n}+1.
$$
Q.E.D.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume $n > 0$ and $\sqrt{n + 1} > 0$ then $\sqrt n > 0$ so $\sqrt{n+1}^2 = n+1 < n + 2 \sqrt{n} + 1 = (\sqrt{n} + 1)^2$

So $\sqrt{n+1} < \sqrt{n}+1$

This relies upon knowing if $a,b > 0$ then $a > b \iff a^2 > b^2$ which is easy to prove and a basic known fact.  Oh, and that $\sqrt{pos} > 0$ .